# HTML,CSS ,JQuery Webpage body too much stretch vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am pretty much done with my project I was going to create a full webpage slider as a background theme for my website and it is working flawlessly!

The issue is that its too stretched vertically, you are able to scroll to the right (You should not be able to do that) & I have no idea on why it is acting like that right now.
I've been trying to fix it with JavaScript but it didnt do anything so I am here to look for some answers.
What I am trying to accomplish is to have a fixed sized webpage both horizontally(Its alreay fixed) and vertically (Which I cant seem to get to work).
It seems to work fine on fiddle (Im new to fiddle)

Here is my fiddle & source code.

https://jsfiddle.net/z8vqp7fe/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Full Width Responsive Image Slider</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
html,body,img {padding: 0; margin: 0;height:100%;width:100%}
body {font-family: Sans-Serif;}

.container{

    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.cycle-slideshow {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
.cycle-prev, .cycle-next {
    font-size: 200;
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -16px;
    z-index: 9999;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.cycle-prev {left: 10%;}
.cycle-next{right: 10%;}


.cycle-pager{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    position: top;
    bottom: 20px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.cycle-pager span {
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;

}
.cycle-pager .cycle-pager-active {background: #FFF;}

  </style>
</head>



<body>


<!-- Full Width Responsive Slider -->

  <div class="cycle-slideshow">
    <span class="cycle-prev">&#9001;</span>
    <span class="cycle-next">&#9002;</span>
    <span class="cycle-pager"></span>
    <img src="images/Untitled.png">
    <img src="images/wp.png">
    <img src="images/wp2.png">
  </div>

<!-- Full Width Responsive Slider -->



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not able to find stretch in Fiddle

Comment: "you are able to scroll to the right (You should not be able to do that)" You said it's overstretched vertically, yet you mention that it scrolls to the right which is the undesired behavior. Vertical is up and down, horizontal is left and right. Vertical is y-axis and horizontal is x-axis. This is hard to figure out since the fiddle doesn't exhibit either abnormalities.

Comment: Also what is "position: top;" in the .cycle-pager container?

Comment: Oh my.. Im so sorry! It is working fine vertically it is the horizontal scroll that is giving me a hard time. It is working fine on fiddle but when I open it(The Index.html) from my folder and load it up on firefox and you can scroll alot to the right like this.

http://imgur.com/KmTu7iS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this
Btw.. there is no such thing as `position: top`;
and `font-size: 200` should be either `200%`, `200em`, or `200px`, etc..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Full Width Responsive Image Slider</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    html,
    body,
    img {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%
    }

    body {
      font-family: Sans-Serif;
    }

    .container {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .cycle-slideshow {
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .cycle-prev,
    .cycle-next {
      font-size: 200%;
      color: #FFF;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      margin-top: -16px;
      z-index: 9999;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .cycle-prev {
      left: 10%;
    }

    .cycle-next {
      right: 10%;
    }

    .cycle-pager {
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 20px;
      z-index: 9999;
    }

    .cycle-pager span {
      text-indent: 100%;
      white-space: nowrap;
      ;
      width: 12px;
      height: 12px;
      display: inline-block;
      border: 1px solid #FFF;
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin: 0 10px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .cycle-pager .cycle-pager-active {
      background: #FFF;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <!-- Full Width Responsive Slider -->

    <div class="cycle-slideshow">
      <span class="cycle-prev">&#9001;</span>
      <span class="cycle-next">&#9002;</span>
      <span class="cycle-pager"></span>
      <img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg">
      <img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg">
      <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-rZmCIp0C-hQ/Tx6aCFeweoI/AAAAAAAAAnQ/WqIEVBTIzRk/s1600/Cool-Tiger-Wallpaper-1920x1080-HD.jpg">
    </div>

    <!-- Full Width Responsive Slider -->


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you be specific what you changed? Would help the OP not have to dig through what's different in your code vs his.

Comment: @Guille looks good to me. You should explain what you did and what OP did wrong.

Comment: That worked! I cant see the difference from my code & yours & there is a small white gap at the bottom, Im sure I can fix it if I knew what was changed. Il look for it!

Comment: I fixed the gap I added " height: 100%; " to

.cycle-slideshow {
     height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0 auto;

  }

Comment: @VargaDev yeah... sorry i forgot to comment my changes in the code.. what you forgot to do was create a div container for you slide show.. i created a `div` named container. you have it in your css but not in your html